# pthread_barrier_t on Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, pthreads

I'm trying to parallelize an algorithm in C on Android NDK with pthreads.

Up to now everything worked quite good. To optimize my code, i tried to use `pthread_barrier_t`.

But when i try to compile it with ndk-build, this error message appears:

```
jni/singleFFT.c:6:1: error: unknown type name 'pthread_barrier_t'
```

Everything else works good. Creating pthreads and joining them... but just trying to add a pthread_barrier_t causes this error. (pthread.h is included)

Is the pthread_barrier_t not supported on Android or what do i need to do?
Perhaps a flag in the Android.mk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bionic libc doesn't provide Barriers synchronization primitive (`pthread_barrier_t` type and related functions) in Android NDK.

https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/pthread.h

Comment: Ok. That's at least an answer and i know why it doesn't work. Seems like i have to build the barrier functionality with mutex. Thanks.

Comment: Android NDK added `pthread_barrier_t` since API level 24. See https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/336.